# S3 Key in AWS::S3::Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an S3 bucket and I want to upload a javascript code into that.
Below are my cloudformation script.

```
MyLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Lambda function to call a Docker image
    FunctionName:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-v1'
      - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
        TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
    EphemeralStorage:
      Size: 10240
    Code:
      S3Bucket: !Ref MyS3Bucket
      S3Key: "lambda-code.zip"
    Runtime: nodejs20.x
    Handler: index.handler
    Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn

MyLambdaExecutionRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName:
      !Sub
      - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-role"
      - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    Policies:
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-role-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
              Resource: "*"

MyS3Bucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheBucketRegion}'
      - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
        TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheBucketRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
```

When my code pipeline runs, I am getting the below error

> Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6a1d0144-97ce-413a-8efe-94572ace7980)" (RequestToken: 47866741-293b-8590-b5e8-508d9945265b, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

I have few questions on this.

1. When I upload some code to S3, should I first zip the file manually and upload to s3 manually? Or will cloudformation do this for me? Bit unclear here.
2. When do I need to specify S3Key attribute when creating my lambda resource? Is the S3Key mandatory?
3. If the answer to Q1 is "yes", then I cannot club all the mentioned S3 resources in my cloudformation right? Because without the zip file in S3 bucket, the "MyLambdaFunction" will fail?
   So ideally I need to first create the S3 bucket alone first, upload the zip file and again incude the remaining resources? Bit confusing..

Appreciate your help.

Comment: When creating a Lambda function, you will typically supply the source code in a Zip file. (It is also possible to write the function in-line in the CloudFormation template, but this is only feasible for very short, simple functions.) It appears that you are saying that the zip file is in `MyS3Bucket`, but that is the bucket being created by another part of the template. Thus, this new does not actually contain the Zip file. Instead, put the Zip file in an **existing bucket** and reference it in `MyLambdaFunction`.

Comment: The general steps are: Write a Lambda function, test it, etc. Save it in a zip file on your computer. Upload the zip file to an (existing) S3 bucket. When writing the template, reference that zip file when defining the Lambda function. Alternatively, do not use CloudFormation -- instead, just write the function and create it using the CLI or the Lambda management console.

Comment: you'll find the SAM CLI is easier for deploying lambdas https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/install-sam-cli.html